# What happened to the magical dagger Duncan stole from the Circle of Magi's First Enchanter?

Tags: dragon-age

In the DA book "The Calling" Duncan steals a magical dagger that has the power to repel the blight. What is the fate of this dagger? You would think this would be highly prized by the grey wardens, but I see no further mention of it.

Comment: Not an answer, but this book looks like a completely shameless ripoff of the Wheel of Time books.